# Why do I get the warning "In edit.data.frame(x) : added factor levels in 'name'" using edit(x)

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> x<-data.frame(name=character(),age=numeric(0))
> x<-edit(x)
```

> Warning message:
> In edit.data.frame(x) : added factor levels in 'name'

Comment: Did you add rows to your table when you edited it? Are you running R version <4.0?

Comment: yes,i added, but the R in mac is 3.6.3, is there any influence?

Comment: Try it with `x<-data.frame(name=character(),age=numeric(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` otherwise your character column is changed to a factor and you get the warning when adding new levels to factor. The coercion to factor doesn't happen in newer versions of R.

Comment: thanks, i tried just now, it works, a good solution,